# Does FCM allow registering the android application from Backend server to receive the notification from FCM on device

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Does FCM allow registering the android application from the Backend server to receive the notification from FCM on the device

Answer (score 0):

You will always need to [get the device token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) on the device itself, but once you have that you can [manage topic subscriptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics) for that token on the server.

Comment: But on the client app, we put this file called "google-services.json", does it contain any sensitive information, if someone tries to sneak in to this file by doing the apk extraction. Any broadcast message which we are sending to our app will be received by there app as well

Comment: Messages sent to topics are as secure at the topic names you use, so you'd typically only want to use those for messages that don't require security. When you target a message to a token though, it'll only be delivered to that specific token - so for tight control it is more common to send directly to tokens.